# Drupal 7 Views - Group By Content Type and Taxonomy Term

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, view, content-type, drupal-taxonomy

I'm hoping there is a solution for this within Drupal that's not too difficult.

I have 2 content types, 1 is Brochures and the other is Product Cards, I've created a view that has grouped these 2 together, however i need to also group by Taxonomy Term, for example by print size: A4 or A5 so the list will look like as follows...

**Brochures (A4)**

- Item #1
- Item #2
- item #3

**Product Cards (A4)**

- Item #1
- Item #2
- item #3

**Product Cards (A5)**

- Item #1
- Item #2
- item #3

Is there a solution for this or would i need to preprocess that view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix this i used 2 views and set them as blocks to add on the same page.

Firstly, got items by content type which displayed all my items needed.
Secondly, set view to show individual fields, this way i could group by taxonomy term which got my desired view.

It was simple enough, i was probably over complicating.